# Capturing key presses in datagridview cells in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, keydown, keyup, key-events

I'm trying to develop a results box that pops when I start to type in cell in the datagridview, something similar to what Chrome does when you type in the address bar.

I've done most of it, the main problem I'm having is trying to capture and handle arrow key presses (up and down).
I've caste the cell control to a textbox so I can grab key presses and pass them to the result box so it know what results to display.

```
tx.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(tx_PreviewKeyDown);
tx.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(tx_KeyDown);
tx.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tx_KeyPress);
```

that works all fine, the problem is, when I press the arrow key down, the tx_PreviewKeyDown captures it, then it disappears until its caught in the datagridview_KeyUp event, by then, its too late and the datagridview has shifted the active cell downwards.

I can handle the event in the tx_PreviewKeyDown and pass that down to move the highlighted value in the result box fine, but what I need to do is prevent it from shifting the active cell downwards into the new row.

I need to be able to cancel the keypress, but the PreviewKeyDown doesn't have a e.Handle flag, either that I need to find what KeyDown event is fired after the tx_PreviewKeyDown but before datagridview_KeyUp event.  Something handles that arrow key, but what?!

Comment: I think that you have to set IsInputKey to true in the PreviewKeyDown event handler in order to have the KeyDown and KeyPress events be raised.

Comment: I don't really understand the question... So you want to know how to capture the arrow keys to see if they are pressed such as left: 37, top: 38, right: 39, down 40?

Comment: yeah, I tried the IsInputKey flag but that has no affect.

Comment: @AlexWhite yeah, pretty much.  The tx_previewKeyDown captures the key press and the e.KeyValue == 40, after that I'd expect it to be passed to the tx_KeyDown, or datagridview_KeyDown but it doesn't.  The next event that is fired is the datagridview_KeyUp event which is too late.

Comment: What if you accept the key down event on the datagridview then check what cell is selected?

Comment: the KeyDown event on the datagridview only fires if I'm not editing the cell.

Comment: Well can you use key up instead? Can you accomplish the same result by  subscribing to the datagridviews key up event and when triggered when certain key is pressed and a cell is selected do your logic?

Comment: @AlexWhite, yes technically I _could_ use the KeyUp event, but then I'd be resetting everything how it was before it was triggered.  Much like rebuilding a house after its burnt down saying it never happened though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always extend the DataGridView and use the WndProc method:

```
class exDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    private const int KEYUP = 38;
    private const int KEYDOWN = 40;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                if (m.WParam == (IntPtr)KEYDOWN)
                {
                    // Do key down stuff...
                    return;
                }
                else if (m.WParam == (IntPtr)KEYUP)
                {
                    // Do key up stuff...
                    return;
                }
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you might have had something, but it appears that when you're editing a cell the DataGridView control doesn't receive any messages relating to WM_KEYDOWN.

Comment: Ok.. it looks like I might have found a work around, very similar to what you've suggested.
Instead of using the WndProc, I've use this instead
    _protected override bool ProcessKeyPreview(ref Message m)_

Comment: I didn't test it with any cells, I just presumed it would work. At least it put you on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the ff. events

**CellBeginEdit** - this event will fire when you start typing in the cell,
**CellEndEdit**  - when you lost focus in the cell,
**DataError** - if error occur during data input